# How To Load Partial View after AJAX Insert as Flash Message

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, partial-views

I have a partial view in my system, which i include in all of my views which then displays any of the flash messages I might have coming from controller. I just started using jQuery and inserting record into my db dynamically.

Allthrough script works(found it elsewhere and modified it), I want to change how i load my flash messages, I dont want to specify them on my view files in script section, I want to send them from my controller and load my partial view like I do on my other pages.

part of my script;

```
        $('#submit').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: postURL,
                method: "POST",
                data: $('#add_name').serialize(),
                type: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.error) {
                        printErrorMsg(data.error);
                    } else {
                        i = 1;
                        $('.dynamic-added').remove();
                        $('#add_name')[0].reset();
                        $(".print-success-msg").find("ul").html('');
                        $(".print-success-msg").css('display', 'block');
                        $(".print-error-msg").css('display', 'none');
                        $(".print-success-msg").find("ul").append(
                            '<li>New Project Space has been added</li>');
                    }
                }
            });
        });


        function printErrorMsg(msg) {
            $(".print-error-msg").find("ul").html('');
            $(".print-error-msg").css('display', 'block');
            $(".print-success-msg").css('display', 'none');
            $.each(msg, function (key, value) {
                $(".print-error-msg").find("ul").append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
            });
        }
```

Part of controller

```
    if ($validator->passes()) {
        foreach ($request->input('label') as $key => $value) {
            Space::create([
                'label'=>$value,
                'user_id' => $user,
                'customer_id' =>$customer,
                'project_id' => $projectid,
                ]);
        }
        return response()->json(['success'=>'done']);
    }

    return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
```

part of partial

```
@if ($message = Session::get('success'))
<div class="alertcontainer" id="alertcontainer">
<div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
</div>
</div>

@endif
```

Comment: So send it from controller `return response()->json(['success'=>'This is the alert message']);` And in the view `data.success`

Comment: ... I think I should rephrase my question, how can I display those messages(from controller) via loading the partial in my view with such script in place?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a really cool feature to allow you to load a partial view from the controller into your view via ajax.

Create a partial view, let's call it partialDisplay.  Put your html, css, and any loops with the `$variable` and any `<ul>`s inside into this view and take it out of the ajax success function.  Then, you can just call your partial and send the actual message.

Name a section of the partial view (say 'messageContent') to be called by the controller.  The partial can still load any base views or other dependencies, but we will focus on the area you need, messageContent

**Partial View:**

```
@extends('layouts.baseModal')

 @section('messageContent')
    // css, loops of data, etc go here
     @foreach($var as $v)
        <li>{{$v->somethingLikeNameOrmessage}}</li>
   // etc
 @stop
```

**Controller:**

```
$view = view('partialDisplay', compact('yourVar(s)'));

    $sections = $view->renderSections(); // returns an associative array of 'content', 'pageHeading' etc

    return $sections['messageContent']; // this will only return whats in the content section
```

Then, in **ajax**, you can just stick in the whole view, complete with formatting, etc:

```
success: function (html) {
       $("#yourMessageDiv").html(html);
 },
```